# ColorSpacePoint to DepthSpacePoint

Tags: c#, c++, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am trying to map a single ColorSpacePoint to a DepthSpacePoint in the Kinect SDK 2.0.

If understand the three types of coordinate systems Kinect provides, this should be a pretty easy mapping. Both ColorSpace and DepthSpace are 2 dimensional spaces they just have different resolutions and aspect ratios.

However, I cannot figure out which function in CoordinateMapper would receive a specific ColorSpacePoint and return the associated DepthSpacePoint.

Can anybody shed some light on this matter?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: This may be helpful https://github.com/wieden-kennedy/Cinder-Kinect2/blob/master/src/Kinect2.cpp#L223

Comment: Thanks Rafaf, it is the opposite operation that I need...

Comment: @Pol I am also having the same problem. I want the depth of a particular coordinate in the color image. What I am doing is that I am tracking a ball in color image using opencv which gives me the center coordinates of ball in color frame, now I want to get the depth of the center coordinate of the ball.So far what I have done is, `MapColorFrameToDepthSpace()` and after that get the depth coordinate coressponding to the color coordinate of ball and then get the depth value from depth frame from the mapped coordinate.
But the result that I am getting is somehow not Correct.

Comment: @Pol If you were able to get the thing done, can you post it here how you did it?

Comment: Not really, Shubham... Per the explanation given by HenningJ there is no real way to accomplish this. Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no method in the SDK that maps a single `ColorSpacePoint` to the `DepthSpace` (or to the `CameraSpace`). And there can't be! To get the correct mapping, you don't only need the pixel coordinates, but also the depth at that specific pixel. And in the RGB image, you don't have that information.

To achieve a correct mapping from color space to depth or camera space, you first have to map the *complete* depth image to the color image, to get depth values for each color pixel. Then it would be easy map a single pixel from color to depth space. But by then you have the complete mapping anyway.

So, if you really need to go in that direction, you need to map the whole image using [`CoordinateMapper.MapColorFrameToCameraSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.coordinatemapper.mapcolorframetocameraspace.aspx).

On the other hand, when you are in the depth or camera space, you already have all the information you need at each pixel, so mapping single pixels is easy. That's why those methods exist (e.g. [`CoordinateMapper.MapDepthPointToCameraSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.coordinatemapper.mapdepthpointtocameraspace.aspx)).

**Edit:**

I hope a little drawing can help explain why the depth is needed to get a correct mapping between color and depth space:

[image]

One of the color camera's pixels is looking at the blue object (the solid blue arrow). This pixel is mapped to a specific pixel of the depth camera (solid red arrow).

If the object wasn't there, the same pixel of the color camera would be looking at the background (dashed blue arrow), which would be mapped to a different pixel in the depth camera (dashed red arrow - different direction of the arrows means different pixels).

But the color camera doesn't know if it's looking at the object or the background. It just knows which color is there. Not how far away that color is. That's why the color camera alone can't decide which is the correct pixel in the depth camera.

The depth camera, on the other hand, knows the distance at each pixel, so it can figure out the corresponding pixel in the color camera.

Comment: Please forgive me if I'm wrong, but So far I know ... `ColorSpacePoint` and `DepthSpacePoint` are just 2D points in 2D plane. They just have different ratio at their Width and Height. If it's true, then, mapping those considering their ratio should be possible. Also, [`DepthSpacePoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.depthspacepoint.aspx) and [`CameraSpacePoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.cameraspacepoint.aspx) aren't same.

Comment: Sure, just mapping between those ratios is not a problem. But mapping between depth and color space is not just a straight pixel mapping. Because of the different camera positions, the depth plays a role in the mapping and must be considered.

Comment: And yes, `DepthSpacePoint` and `CameraSpacePoint` are different data structures. But they are directly related. For each DepthSpacePoint (and the corresponding depth value), you can directly calculated the matching CameraSpacePoint. They basically hold the same information, just in a different format.

Comment: @HenningJ I understand that the two spaces are slightly misaligned because they come from different cameras. However if there is a way to map from DepthSpace to ColorSpace why can't there be a way to go in the opposite direction?

Comment: Because the DepthSpace has 3D information, while the ColorSpace only has 2D information. And the 3D information is necessary for the correct mapping. I added an image to my answer, hopefully explaining it better.

Comment: Thanks! That explains things :)